# How can I make Visual Studio Code recognize html, php and javascript all in one file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I started using Visual Studio Code and I have noticed that it recognizes only one language at a time. Is there a way to change that so that I can have 3 recognized languages (HTML, JavaScript, PHP) all in the same .php file?

So I can get colors and snippets and such for all 3 languages at the same time

Answer (score 2):

From vscode [1.20 (Jan 2018)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_global-snippets) it's possible to create *Global snippets*:

```json
{
    "check": {
        "scope": "html,javascript,php",
        "prefix": "check",
        "body": [
            "✅"
        ]
    }
}
```

To make it work in all languages simply omit the `"scope"`

Comment: Global snippets are now in general release 1.20 Feb.2018

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would use only one of them per file, but using the PHP language the editor supports all these languages.

[image]

Comment: the question was clear "code and snippets".. VS code detects colors but it didn't walk through snippets.On the other side, in some cases  you need to add some code in php such as view in MVC approach.. same thing applied to javascript

Comment: It works with snippets of the three languages on PHP files.